# Cannot connect to Redis in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, ioredis

I try to connect to Redis from my backend, but I keep getting the following error:

```
...
api-1    | [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
api-1    |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
api-1    | [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
api-1    |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
...
```

Here is how I config my redis client:

```js
import Redis from "ioredis";

export const redisConfig = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    return `redis://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`;
  }
  return "";
};

const redisCli = new Redis(redisConfig());

export default redisCli;
```

And this is my dockerfile:

```
# ---- Dependencies ---- 

FROM node:16-alpine AS base

# minimize image size
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat 

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm ci


# ---- Builder ---- 

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=base /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY ./src ./src

COPY package*.json tsconfig.json webpack.config.ts ./

RUN npm run build


# ---- Release ---- 

FROM node:16 AS release

WORKDIR /app

# COPY ./prisma ./prisma 

# COPY ./.env ./

# COPY ./deployment ./deployment

COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./

# RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm install pm2 -g 

EXPOSE 3000
```

This one is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build: ./

    depends_on:
      - redis

    links:
      - redis

    command: sh -c "node dist/server.js"

    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - NODE_ENV=production

    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
```

I have specified the links in docker-compose, but still receiving the same error.
How can I fix the error? Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this error because your application is probably trying to connect to redis before redis is up and accessible. In your `depends_on` section, you can say that you want to start your application after your redis service is healthy. To do so, you must also configure a healthcheck to tell when redis is really ready to accept connections (`redis-cli ping` for example).

Here is an example of configuration that works for me:

```yaml
version: "3"                                                                                                                                                                 

services:
  api:
    build: ./

    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy

    links:
      - redis

    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - NODE_ENV=production

  redis:
    image: redis:latest

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to connect with such a config into the Redis hosted in Docker

```
ConfigurationOptions co = new ConfigurationOptions()
        {
            SyncTimeout = 500000,
            EndPoints =
            {
                { "127.0.0.1", 49155 }
            },
            AbortOnConnectFail = false // this prevents that error,
            , Password = "redispw"

        };

RedisConnectorHelper.lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(co); 
        });
```

where 49155  is the doker path port
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check for IP address assigned to Redis in docker using Inspect Docker
docker inspect

```
 ConfigurationOptions co = new ConfigurationOptions()
{
  SyncTimeout = 500000,
  EndPoints =
        {
            { "172.20.0.3", 6379 }
        },
  AbortOnConnectFail = true // this prevents that error,
          

};

 redisDb = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(co);
```